# Need help to create SQL Listener

Tags: sql

In my application, there is an external event (low pressure inside the pipelines) which triggers alarms to be generated. These alarms have a specific format. I want to store these alarms into a MS SQL database. The problem is that I need some sort of listener which will listen to the alarms when generated and will then store it in the SQL database. 
I am working with web application development in ASP.net and C#. I am clueless as to how do I develop these listeners. 
Please suggest me how do i create such a listener.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more detail about the format and delivery method of the alarms?

Comment: the format of the alarms is a key value pair, and the naem of the area where the alarm was generated. I have ceated sql tables too to store the alarms. its just that i need some sort of listener that listens when the alarm is generated and then stores it in the database. 
@abe: this is not a homework, i am currently working on a company project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some software component that interfaces with the pipeline pressure monitors? That seems like your first step - some physical device that monitors pressure and connects to a computer via serial, bluetooth, whatever.

Then a software componeent that knows nothing about SQL that talks to this device and reports events via software notification - email, snmp, whatever.

Then you need somethign that 'listens' to the software component and logs the event in SQL.

Sorry can't be more specific, but that's how I'd approach it.

Comment: There is a third party software that monitors the pressure and creates the alarms. I have the format of the alarms. I can create SQL tables too to store the alarms. Just that when the alarms are generated, i need to design a sort of a listener that can listen "that the alarm has been generated" and "now i need to store it in the database". I need to design the listener. 

@trucker_jim: I will try to search about the .net gauges. thank you.

Comment: Yes, if there's a .Net Api to the third party software, or if its accessible via COM you should have a good starting point.

Comment: How does the 3rd party software broadcast the alarms? Does it send an email, or at HTTP POST, or write data to a file or call a phone number? Need to know what you are listening for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .Net to develop a windows service. It could have a system.threading.timer running which checks the status of the guages at specific intervals looking for alarm criteria. Not sure how you'd interface .Net to the guages though.

Assuming you can access the guage data in .Net, when an alarm criteria is met you could have the windows service write direct to the SQL DB, or use a WCF web service call to write the alarm to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think  best way achiving this with SNMP trap .But device you get pressure information must support this.